# Image with text at the left and a container at right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a page having a banner. The banned contains the title of the page at the left and a box having text and two buttons inside at the right.

The page is completely responsive except the banner because i am not sure how to use top and left while keeping things responsive.

HTML

```
<div class="banner_container"> 
    <img src="img/banner_1.png">
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-7"> 
        <div class="banner-title"><strong>WAKE UP IN BALI</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 trip_inclusions">
        <div class="inclusions_price">
            <div class="total_nights">
                <div class="number_of_nights">12 </div> NIGHTS
            </div>
            <div class="price_grid_wrapper"> 
                <div class="starting_from">STARTING FROM </div>
                <div class="tour_price">
                    <div class="dollar_price_wrapper">
                        <div class="dollar_logo">$</div>
                        <div class="price_text">1250</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="price_tax_text">TAXES INCL/PERS</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inclusions_details">
            <div class="package_includes_title">PACKAGE INCLUDES</div>
            <div class="includes_content">
                <p>+ INTERNATIONAL FLIGHTS</p>
                <p>+ WELCOME & TRANSFERS</p>
                <p>+ HOTEL(12 NIGHTS)</p>
                <p>+ BREAKFASTS</p>
                <p>+ EXCURISIONS</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="package_buttons">
            <div class="share_package"><a href="#">SHARE PACKAGE +</a></div>
            <div class="all_packages"> <a href="#"> < ALL PACKAGES </a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner_container img{
    width: 100%;
}

.banner-title{
    font-size: 160%;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1px gray, 1px 0 gray, -1px 0 gray;
    margin: 48px 25px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.trip_inclusions{
    padding: 2px;
    top: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20em;
}

.inclusions_price {
    background-color: #00467e;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 3px;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
}

.total_nights {
    width: 24%;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 0.95em;
}

.number_of_nights{
    font-size: 3.8em;
    margin-bottom: -13px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.price_grid_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}


.starting_from {
    width: 8%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4em;
    font-size: .95em;
    margin-top: 2px;
}


.tour_price {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}


.dollar_price_wrapper{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dollar_logo{
    float: left;
    font-size:1.5em;
}

.price_text{
    float: left;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.price_tax_text{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: .9em;

}

.inclusions_details{
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 80%;

}

.package_includes_title{
    color: #399fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}

.includes_content{
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.package_buttons{
    margin:0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.share_package{
    background-color: #399fff;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size:1em;
    float: left;
    width:40%;
    text-align: center;
}

.all_packages{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    width:40%;
    color: #00467e;
    font-size:1em;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.share_package a{
    color: white;
}

.share_package a:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

Please have a look at the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gdcref9/). Its not responsive at all also you will see the right container is big, ignore that i`ll fix it but i want text at left and container at right and image at the back and keep it responsive.

Note: I could have used backgroundurl() but i didnt as i am planning to replace the background image with a slider so i need it in a separate

Thanks !!!

Comment: If you want a truly responsive page, don't use 'px'. Make all measurements a percentage of their context.

Comment: Bootstrap columns belong in rows inside containers.

Comment: @j08691 what do you mean?